# relabel x-axis to be consistent with reorder function ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a grouped bar chart in ggplot2, where I have the x-axis as direction of gaze, y-axis percentage of time, and grouped by condition (reliability of robot). I have created a reproducible example of the dataset below.

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

robot_reliability <- c("reliable", "reliable", "reliable", "reliable", "unreliable", "unreliable", "unreliable", "unreliable")
percent_robot <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40)
percent_game <- c(20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 25, 35, 45)
percent_others <- c(6, 8, 10, 12, 11, 9, 7, 5)

data <-  data.frame(robot_reliability, percent_robot, percent_game, percent_others)

gg <- melt(data, id = "robot_reliability")
ggplot(gg, aes(x = reorder(variable, -value), y = value, fill = factor(robot_reliability))) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.min = min, fun.max = max, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey40", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Robot Reliability", labels = c("Reliable", "Unreliable")) +
  xlab("Direction of Gaze") + 
  ylab("Percentage of Overall Interaction Time") +
  ggtitle("Percentage of Time Spent Gazing") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Game", "Robot","Others"))
```

I have ordered my graph from high-low values on the y-axis (percentage of overall interaction time) using the reorder function

```
ggplot(gg, aes(x = reorder(variable, -value), y = value, fill = factor(robot_reliability)))
```

Later on, I have relabelled the axis using scale_x_discrete:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Game", "Robot", "Others"))
```

However, this appears to fix the labels to those positions (so, for example if you remove the '-' from '-value' in reorder, the bar graph would rearrange to go from low-high, but the labels on the x-axis would stay in the same positions, meaning the labels are incorrectly matched to the data. Is there a way to combine the labels on the x-axis with the reorder function so that they are permanently attached to the correct data columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to achieve this. First. Use a named vector to map categories of your variable to labels like I did in the code below. Second. Simply rename the categories in your df or add a column with the labels. This way you will get the correct labels automatically.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

robot_reliability <- c("reliable", "reliable", "reliable", "reliable", "unreliable", "unreliable", "unreliable", "unreliable")
percent_robot <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40)
percent_game <- c(20, 30, 40, 50, 15, 25, 35, 45)
percent_others <- c(6, 8, 10, 12, 11, 9, 7, 5)

data <-  data.frame(robot_reliability, percent_robot, percent_game, percent_others)

gg <- melt(data, id = "robot_reliability")
ggplot(gg, aes(x = reorder(variable, value), y = value, fill = factor(robot_reliability))) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position = position_dodge(1)) +
  stat_summary(fun.min = min, fun.max = max, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey40", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Robot Reliability", labels = c("Reliable", "Unreliable")) +
  xlab("Direction of Gaze") + 
  ylab("Percentage of Overall Interaction Time") +
  ggtitle("Percentage of Time Spent Gazing") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(percent_game = "Game", percent_robot = "Robot", percent_others = "Others"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: using `scale_x_discrete(labels = c(percent_game = "Game", percent_robot = "Robot", percent_others = "Others"))` worked, thank you!